# Unable to find or serve resource, /Directory1/Myproject/index.xhtml

Tags: jsf, navigation

I have a log-out function that implements logout of the user currently in session. This function can be called from many different pages located to various directories in my project. I want , after the function is called , the user to be redirected to the index page. But I cannot achieve this. I know that redirection depends on the return string of the function, but it seems that this string is referring to the current directory.

E.g

```
Myproject
-index.xhtml
--Directory1
---page1.xhtml (this page is located in the Directory1-subdirectory of Myproject)
```

The function is this:

```
String logout(){
..
return "Myproject/index.xhtml"
}
```

which works fine as long as it is called from the index.xhtml

whereas when I call it from the page1.xhtml it doens't work with message:

> Unable to find or serve resource, /Directory1/Myproject/index.xhtml.

is there any way to make this work or should I go for another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add '/'

`String logout(){
    ..
    return "/Myproject/index.xhtml"
    }`